# What are advantages of Processing over general purpose languages for generative art?

Tags: processing

I have red a short book on Processing, but haven't noticed any language features that wouldn't be present in JavaScript and canvas or Java - JavaFX or any other general purpose language that have graphics. Just usual stuff - drawing lines and circles etc. 
So are there any benefits of using processing and could you provide some specific examples? Working with sound perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow isn't really meant for general questions like this. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense.

Programming languages are like tools. Different tools are better at different tasks: a hammer and a wrench are used for different things, for example. Can you technically use a wrench to hammer in nails? Sure, but your life is going to be a lot easier if you just use a hammer. Programming languages are the same.

Processing is designed to make it easy to create animated and interactive programs, with as little boilerplate as possible. Let's consider this program:

```
void draw(){
   ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}
```

This is a complete Processing program. When you run it, it shows a window, gets user input, and draws a circle trail that follows the mouse around. Think about all of the code you'd have to write in Java or JavaScript to get the same thing working.

Sure, it's possible to create a Java or JavaScript program that does the same thing. In fact, Processing itself is built on top of Java or JavaScript, so anything you can do in Processing you can do in one of those languages. But Processing lets you not worry about all of the setup and boilerplate code that those languages require.

On top of that, Processing offers a set of tools that make it easy to deploy your program as an application or as a webpage just by clicking a few buttons. It also comes with an awesome community, tutorials, examples, and a general approach to programming that isn't found in other languages or frameworks.

Your question is a bit like asking: why do we need Java or JavaScript when everything can be written in assembly code? Why do we need assembly code when everything can be written in binary?

Comment: I recommend removing the first paragraph and maybe adding it as a comment on the question. It is not part of an answer to the question.

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks for the comment, but I prefer to leave the disclaimer and the answer as a cohesive whole.

Comment: But that's not the way I would do it! ;p

Comment: @Paulpro [That's just, like, your opinion, man...](http://i.imgur.com/Y0dRszs.gifv)